# ** ERROR ** Could not obtain necessary font info. Output file removed

Tags: fonts

I'm using the font "Ubuntu Mono" under windows.

From the command fc-list, I can see the font Ubuntu Mono, and in Word or other text editors I also can use this font.

But under Latex, I set `\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}`, it gets :

```
** WARNING ** Invalid glyph name index number: 1305 (>= 1305) ** WARNING ** Invalid version 2.0 'post' table
** ERROR ** Could not obtain necessary font info. Output file removed.
xelatex.exe
: Broken pipe
出现错误
```

if I set I set `\setmonofont{UbuntuMono}`(of course I didn't have the font named UbuntuMono), it gets :

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "UbuntuMono" cannot be found. For immediate help type H <return>.
```

following is the information of the font:

```
Ubuntu Mono:style=Regular
csss12:style=Regular
dsss12:style=Regular
```

My Tex code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono} % Consolas % Ubuntu Mono

\usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily,  
 }

\begin{document}

\section{Code}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question, added tex code, please give some help.

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine here with both `lualatex` and `xelatex`. Is your TeX installation up to date? I'm using TeX Live 2016 updated fairly recently. And which version of the font do you have?

Comment: I'm using version 0.80 of the truetype version of Ubuntu Mono. `Family:              Ubuntu Mono
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Ubuntu Mono
PostScript name:     UbuntuMono-Regular
Preferred family:    Ubuntu Mono
Preferred subfamily: Regular
Mac font menu name:  Ubuntu Mono
Version:             Version 0.80
Unique ID:           Ubuntu Mono Regular Version 0.80`

Comment: `Designer:            Dalton Maag Ltd
Designer URL:        http://www.daltonmaag.com/
Manufacturer:        Dalton Maag Ltd
Vendor URL:          http://www.daltonmaag.com/
Trademark:           Ubuntu and Canonical are registered trademarks of Canonical Ltd.
Copyright:           Copyright 2011 Canonical Ltd.  Licensed under the Ubuntu Font Licence 1.0
Vendor ID:           DAMA`

Comment: `otfinfo -i <path to font file>` will give you the corresponding output for the font you have. On my machine, for example, I used `otfinfo -i /usr/share/fonts/ttf-ubuntu-font-family-ib/UbuntuMono-R.ttf`.

Comment: I'm using CTeX 2.9.2.164 toolset(https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ctex/legacy/2.9/)
```This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (MiKTeX 2.9)```
font information:```Family:              Ubuntu Mono
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Ubuntu Mono
PostScript name:     UbuntuMono-Regular
Preferred family:    Ubuntu Mono
Preferred subfamily: Regular
Mac font menu name:  Ubuntu Mono
Version:             Version 0.80
Unique ID:           Ubuntu Mono Regular Version 0.80
Vendor ID:           DAMA```

Comment: I'd suggest installing a current distribution, especially for XeTeX/LuaTeX.